# Most Ideal Way to Run a Scheduled Job with Angular-Meteor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm writing an appointment scheduling app with angular-meteor. One of the requirements is that a text notification be sent out to the customer who made the appointment. The customer provides a cell number. But basically, all I want to do is send out an email X many minutes before the appointment time. Running off the angular-meteor stack, what might be the best way to do this? All of the appointment information is saved to a mongo db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be interested in Meteor [job-collection](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection) package (not specific to angular-meteor):

> A persistent and reactive job queue for Meteor, supporting distributed workers that can run anywhere.
>
> job-collection is a powerful and easy to use job manager designed and built for Meteor.js.
>
> It solves the following problems (and more):
>
> - Schedule jobs to run (and repeat) in the future, persisting across server restarts
> - […]

In particular [`job.after(someTimeBeforeAppointment)`](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection#jobaftertime---anywhere)

```
// Server
var myJobs = JobCollection('myJobQueue');

// Start the myJobs queue running
myJobs.startJobServer();


// Create a Job (e.g. in a Meteor method)
var job = new Job(myJobs, 'jobType', jobData);

// Specify when it can run and save it.
job.after(someTimeBeforeAppointment).save();


// Server (or could be a different server!)
// How jobs should be processed.
myJobs.processJobs('jobType', function (job, done) {
    var jobData = job.data;

    // Do something… could be asynchronous.
    job.done(); // or job.fail();

    // Call done when work on this job has finished.
    done();
});
```

The `pollInterval` can be specified in `processJobs` [options](https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection#jq--jcprocessjobstype-options-worker---anywhere). Default is every 5 seconds.

Comment: This is very enticing. I will definitely research this further.

Comment: do you have experience with this package?

Answer (score 1):

Write a node script that sends an email to every customer who has an appointment between X minutes and X+10 minutes from the time of running. Once the email is sent, set a boolean flag on the appointment in mongo so it doesn't get sent twice.

Run a cron that triggers it every 5 minutes.

The overlap should make sure that nothing slips though the cracks, and the flag will prevent multiples from being sent.

Comment: This will work. I was thinking I could write something server side that would add a cron job for every appointment created. Then that cron would run a script being provided an email address. But your idea would kind of turn it into a batch process.

Comment: You don't want to add crons dynamically, just write a script that checks for notifications that need to be sent. You should also point the cron to output it's log to a file so that you can monitor it for errors.